# Java SQL. Inserting into a table with two primary keys

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem with these blocks of code. I think its a SQL problem I am having. This code is supposed to create a student table and insert data from my android application into the student table. I am getting a error saying the courseid column doesn't exist. I think the problem has to do with courseid being declared a primary key in my course table.

Creating Course table:

```
  public static String createTable(){
    return "CREATE TABLE " + DbSchema.TABLE_Course  + "("
            + DbSchema.KEY_CourseId  + " PRIMARY KEY    ,"
            + DbSchema.KEY_Name_Course + " TEXT )";
}
```

Creating Student table:

```
public static String createTable(){
    return "CREATE TABLE " + DbSchema.TABLE_Student  + "("
            + DbSchema.KEY_StudID  + " PRIMARY KEY  ,"
            + DbSchema.KEY_Name_Student + " TEXT, "
            + DbSchema.KEY_Year_Student + " TEXT, "
            + DbSchema.KEY_Email_Student+ " TEXT,"
            + DbSchema.KEY_CourseId+" TEXT )";
}
```

Inserting into table:

```
public void insert(Student student) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DbSchema.KEY_StudID, student.getid());
    values.put(DbSchema.KEY_Name_Student, student.getname());
    values.put(DbSchema.KEY_Year_Student, student.getYear());
    values.put(DbSchema.KEY_Email_Student, student.getEmail());
    values.put(DbSchema.KEY_CourseId, student.getCourseid());




    db.insert(DbSchema.TABLE_Student, null, values);
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
```

Create Table command:

```
   public DBHelper( ) {
    super(App.getContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //All necessary tables you like to create will create here
    db.execSQL(CourseDbCommands.createTable());
    db.execSQL(StudentDbCommands.createTable());
```

Comment: Missing space `DbSchema.KEY_CourseId  + "PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: can you check that student course id already exist on the course table?

Comment: The columns do exists in both student and course table. It is only when I try to add in a value into course id in the student table I get an error:

 04-15 13:14:54.784 3033-3033/com.toddinc.classhelperproject E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Student has no column named CourseId

Comment: First you add course id into course table and then insert to student table. I mention this on my answer as well.

Comment: No table can have 2 primary keys. Problem solved.

Comment: Whatever I use for that last column doesn't work. If I name it something completely different it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between `DbSchema.TABLE_Course  + "("` and `DbSchema.KEY_CourseId  + "PRIMARY KEY`

Student table as also have same spacing problem.

```
DbSchema.TABLE_Student  + "("
```

or

check that student course id already exist on the course table

Comment: I added those adjustments but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any foreign key reference in your student table creation command.
for reference, you can check this[enter link description here](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

I also assume you already have some entry in course table to map with student table. i.e before you insert a student with a particular course in student table that course should be present in course table.

Comment: I didn't mean to add in "foreign key" that was me just messing around. I took that part out. Right now I simply want to add in a column to the student table named 'courseid.' There is already a column in the course table named that. would that cause error in my program?

Comment: The column in Course Table should not give you this issue. Can you share your create table command for Student table?

Comment: So have you removed that foreign key or do you have any relationship between Student and Course table

Comment: Ok  the code is there. Yes I removed that piece. No references to foreign keys at all.

Comment: I was not asking for that. I just meant the create table statement. U said that you changed that foreign key part so I was asking what change you made.

Comment: The part where it said foreign key above was the only mention or use of foreign key in my program. I removed that piece so now its:

+ DbSchema.KEY_CourseId+" TEXT )";

Comment: In your Primary key also you have not mentioned data type, did you resolved that too?

Comment: I just resolved that too. issue still exists. I use DB browser for sql lite and it I am certain the column is there. the issue comes when I try to insert into that row.

Comment: Can you check query which is generated by your code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I had to change the version of my database manually. I thought changes automatically happened.

Answer (score 0):

### I think your have missed INTEGER in your declaration

```
   public static String createTable(){
        return "CREATE TABLE " + DbSchema.TABLE_Student  + "("
                + DbSchema.KEY_StudID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,"
                + DbSchema.KEY_Name_Student + " TEXT, "
                + DbSchema.KEY_Year_Student + " TEXT, "
                + DbSchema.KEY_Email_Student+ " TEXT,"
                + DbSchema.KEY_CourseId+" TEXT )";
    }
```